# Regex match a function if only if it contains a specific variable

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this string that I have read from a file.

```
    /**********************************************************************functionheaderstuff***********************************************************************************************************************/
void fn1(void)
{   
    b= 8;
}

/***********************************************************************functionheaderstuff***********************************************************************************************************************/

void fn2(int a, intb)
{   int c;

    var = 6;
}
```

I want to match the function which contains the variable var which is written.

With this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dgDQ2k/2) `(?<=[*]{60}\/)(\s*\w+(?: \w+\s*)(?=(\((.*?)\)\s*{))).*(\bvar\b([^>=<!;{])*[=]{1}[^=]*?[;])`, I am matching both the functions as the .* is greedy. I need it to not match if it encounters `}\s*\/[*]{60}` and only match if the function contains the variable being written, preferably only if the variable is not within a comment.

Negative lookahead didn't work- `((?<=[*]{60}\/)\s*\w+(?: \w+\s*)(?=(\((.*?)\)\s*{)).*)(?!(\s*}\s*\/[*]{60}))(\bvar\b([^>=<!;{])*[=]{1}[^=]*?[;])`

My function will start with the type of function header I shared. Finding variable being written into and identifying the function works okay.
This regex works fine if the function contains the var else it takes from the next function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could achieve your target, in a more simple way. which is not necessary to be in one regex.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to work this out. It would be best if this could be made to work. If there is an easier way, would you mind pointing it out?

Comment: Parsing C code with regex is just as crazy as parsing HTML with regex. Use a proper parser instead.

Comment: Crazy as in there will always be more corner cases? I have almost gotten what I needed which is extracting global var info across files and functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach and got what I needed. I removed all the comments initially. I matched the functions in the string and made it to a list. Then checked for the variable.
[Python code](https://tio.run/##NZBRT4MwFIWf119R9yAtIBFNjBniYqIPS6a@zKe2S2ArrAkrpNQNhvx2bAX70N57z7lfclq1@lDK@2EQx6pUGiqe8wZo3mgYw/l8firFHmYyRLbAHRxPGsPHqIeTeIeE1DDxoXnSP4/td5F1nhJlQA9Rb1ig1krIPDQD5dCzh5YLWnumwK65CGKEnn0auLS@poQy5hLMaO2izhjJtuuZ5/2gZYix22MHAIM@K6H5iEtNS1NEts/x01XUMeySmHVhT7Yxc5ckYg4w2azXJgx25bESBUf/EH8cv3@tN6v16uMNYtDCmDRBrsrvCmGYlQo2Jti0nwm5N2sKTZl8@2UT5PVz87JeYwYqI2nUYmCXCyH5334ic44KLo2AF2AmMosMap6o3QG1xPqYFWYXGE9tUFeF0MhBjh9icsuMOLIvk4LJTcgwGIZf)

```
import regex
text = """void fn1(void){       b= 8;} void fn2(int a, intb){   int c;    var = 6;}"""

#checks for complete function definition
string1 = r'\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\w+[(][\w,\.*\s&\[\]]*[)]\s*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})'

varwrite = r'\bvar\b([^>=<!;{])*[=]{1}[^=]*?[;]'
reg = regex.compile(varwrite,regex.MULTILINE )
y =[x.group() for x in regex.finditer(string1,text,regex.DOTALL)]
print(y)
for line in range(len(y)):
    if reg.search(y[line]):
        z =y[line].split('(',1)[0]
        print(z.split()[-1])
```